# Flutter Cubit Stuck on initial state

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc, cubit

I've been trying to call a function to fetch data from firebase firestore as a list using cubit, but somehow it didnt update the state (stuck on initial state) after I'm calling `context.read<LocationHistoryCubit>().getLocationHistoryInitial.`  What do i do wrong here?

I have tried declaring the bloc provider in main.dart, also I have tried using bloc provider wrapping my widget tree

here's my cubit class:

```
class LocationHistoryCubit extends Cubit<LocationHistoryState> {
  LocationHistoryCubit() : super(LocationHistoryInitial());
  final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Future<String?> getNamaPerusahaan() async {
    String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
    log("Current uid : $uid");
    final docRef = db.collection("DataUser").doc(uid).withConverter(
      fromFirestore: UserModel.fromFirestore,
      toFirestore: (UserModel userModel, _) => userModel.toFirestore(),
    );
    final docSnap = await docRef.get();
    final user = docSnap.data();
    log("user company name : ${user?.companyId}");
    return user?.companyId;
  }

  void getLocationHistoryInitial(String idKendaraan) async {
    //TODO : convert custom date time
    emit(LocationHistoryLoading());
    String? companyName = await getNamaPerusahaan();
    List<LatLng> latLngList = [];
    DateTime dateInit = DateTime.now();

    TimeOfDay timeEndRaw = const TimeOfDay(hour: 23, minute: 59);
    TimeOfDay timeStartRaw = const TimeOfDay(hour: 00, minute: 01);

    DateTime dateStart = DateTime(
        dateInit.year, dateInit.month, dateInit.day, timeStartRaw.hour,
        timeStartRaw.minute);
    DateTime dateEnd = DateTime(
        dateInit.year, dateInit.month, dateInit.day, timeEndRaw.hour,
        timeEndRaw.minute);

    String timeStartFormat = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm').format(dateStart);
    String timeEndFormat = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm').format(dateEnd);


    final docRef = db.collection("DataPerusahaan").doc(companyName).collection(
        'DaftarKendaraan')
        .doc(idKendaraan).collection("LocationHistory")
        .where(
        'TIS', isGreaterThan: timeStartFormat, isLessThan: timeEndFormat)
        .orderBy(
        'TIS', descending: false);

    var docSnap = await docRef.get();
    final latlong = docSnap.docs;

    for (var coord in latlong) {
      GeoPoint location = coord.get('GeoPoint');
      latLngList.add(
          LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
      );
    }
    log("latLong List : ${latLngList.length}");

    if (latLngList.isEmpty) {
      emit(LocationHistoryEmpty());
    } else {
      emit(LocationHistoryComplete(latLngList));
    }
  }
}
```

here's my main.dart :

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/home',
      routes: {
        '/history' : (context) => MultiBlocProvider(
            providers: [
              BlocProvider(
                  create: (context)=>AuthCubit()
              ),
              BlocProvider(
                  create: (context)=>LocationHistoryCubit()
              ),
            ],
            child: const NewLocationHistory()
        ),
```

here's my state classs

```
@immutable
abstract class LocationHistoryState {}

class LocationHistoryInitial extends LocationHistoryState {}

class LocationHistoryLoading extends LocationHistoryState{}

class LocationHistoryComplete extends LocationHistoryState{
  List<LatLng> latLongList;
  LocationHistoryComplete(this.latLongList);
}

class LocationHistoryError extends LocationHistoryState{}

class LocationHistoryEmpty extends LocationHistoryState{}
```

here's my widget tree :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: BlocBuilder<LocationHistoryCubit, LocationHistoryState>(
          builder: (context, state){
            log("Location History : $state");
            if(state is LocationHistoryEmpty){
              log("Location History : $state");
              log("Location History Error");
            }else if(state is LocationHistoryComplete){
              return FlutterMap(
                options: MapOptions(
                    center: LatLng(-6.9022141, 107.622682), zoom: 14),
                children: [
                  TileLayer(
                    urlTemplate:
                    'https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                  ),
              
              PolylineLayer(
                polylines: [
                  Polyline(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      strokeWidth: 2,
                      points: state.latLongList)
                ],
              )
                ],
              );
            }else if(state is LocationHistoryError){
              log("Location History : $state");
              log("Location History Error");
            }
            return Container();
          }
      ),
    );
```

here's where i'm calling `context.read<LocationHistoryCubit>().getLocationHistoryInitial.` inside IconButton in another page

```
IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    //log("Markers id : ${markers[1].key}");
                                    context.read<LocationHistoryCubit>().getLocationHistoryInitial(document.id);
                                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/history',
                                        arguments: document.id);
                                  },
                                  icon: jenisKendaraan == "Motor"
                                      ? const Icon(Icons.motorcycle)
                                      : const Icon(Icons.directions_car))
```

Comment: Where you call `context.read<LocationHistoryCubit>().getLocationHistoryInitial` ?

Comment: I have updated my code snippet above, feel free to check it out @DanielRoldán

Comment: Probably is that LocationHistoryCubit is not in that page, if you want to do global your Cubit, just wrap your MaterialApp with the MultiblocProvider instead in the router. Try that

Comment: Agree with Dan, maybe your icon button doesn't place at file/screen it should be

Comment: I have try that, but still no change. it still stuck on initial state. Any chance of mistake in my cubit class? @DanielRoldán

Comment: It's weird, idk when calling your function at least its emits the `LocationHistoryLoading` ? Also in your function put Future<void> instead void

Comment: it is weird, I have never encounter this issue before. and no it's not emitting `LocationHistoryLoading` either, since the super call of LocHistoryCubit is LocationHistoryInitial

Comment: it should be able to emit it's state even if i call `context.read<LocationHistoryCubit>().getLocationHistoryInitial` in different page or routes as long as I have provided the `BlocProvider` in that page right? @DanielRoldán

Comment: If you have your Bloc or Cubit global, above the MaterialApp it should work; also what you can try is not to call it in button, in your History page, make it StatefulWidget and in the InitState call your function, see what happens. @FikriAbdullah